# Creating multiple objects for spring boot best practice

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using spring boot.Please suggest the best practice in my scenario.

**I have person class with parametrs-:

name, address, sex,companyWorking,age,profession etc.**.

these parameters i will receive from another system as personDTO object which will come in body as post request

So i am writing a create person api.**Here i cant use spring bean as it is singleton and at a time multiple requests can come.(get/post refer note3 below)**

So create api function will be calling below func.
**Please suggest best way to create multiple objects by leveraging spring boot features instead of using new Person**

**Note-: 1) i am saving person class in db.


Note-: 2) i am taking personDto object in body param as same dto object is used to create other classes in project which will have extra paramters for other classes.So don't focus on personDto class.


Note 3-: I can not use singleton as lets say someone is using get api then as it is singleton it will contradict it will return wrong parametrs. Hence new is used.**

```
void createPerson(personDto pDto)
{
   Person p = new Person();
   p.setName(pDto.getName());
   P.setAge(pDto.getAge());
   p.setSex(pDto.getSex());
   .
   "like this and opening transaction session to rollback if object is not 
   created"
}
```

Comment: *i cant use spring bean as it is singleton and at a time multiple requests can come.*: this is where you're wrong. A singleton is perfectly able to process several requests concurrently. It needs to be thread-safe, that's all. But controllers are usually stateless, and thus thread-safe.

Comment: i can not  use singleton as lets say someone is using get api then as it is singleton it will contradict it will return wrong parametrs. Hence new is used.

Comment: I do not fully get your question. What exactly do you need to get answered? Whether there is a nicer way to create your "data object" (`Person`) instead of using `new Person(...)`?

Comment: Yes,best way to create multiple objects by leveraging spring boot features instead of using new Person

Comment: *i can not use singleton as lets say someone is using get api then as it is singleton it will contradict it will return wrong parametrs*: no, it won't. Each thread has its own stack, and the local variables used by one method execution in one thread won't be the same as the other local variables used in the execution of the same method in another thread. And each thread needs to create a new person, so using `new Person()`is the right, correct thing to do.

Comment: Yeah correct i cant use the person bean object[by autowiring in my service class where above function is there] i have to create a new person everytime, which spring boot says we should avoid objects creation and use beans.So i want to avaoid doing new person and use spring boot featurs for object creation.Please suggest best way.

Comment: Not everything needs to be a Spring bean. Your Person object (which, I guess, is a JPA entity or something similar), certainly shouldn't be.

Comment: why complicate it? just use ```new Person```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `Person` can't be a singleton, since you create these objects upon each request, understood.
Now, if you absolutely need it, you can create a Person as a bean with a prototype scope in Spring.

The service that will convert a PersonDTO into Person will be a singleton as was already stated in comments but its "convert" method could get the prototype.

There are many technical ways to inject prototype into a singleton. Take a look [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton)

However, I would like to emphasize that, unlike singletons, instances of prototype-scoped beans **are not stored in the application context**. Otherwise, Application Context would explode keeping too-many references (I mean Out Of Memory errors)

So you will gain basically the following:

- Spring will do a "new" not you
- Post Construct can be called if defined (but not so for the pre-destroy method)
- If you'll have dependencies in this class, spring will inject them for you. This seems to be not the case in the case of object conversion like yours.

So what's the point using Spring at this point?

Personally (and this is only my opinion/recommendation) tend to deal with various convertes, builders, and so forth outside Spring, keeping services/controllers (long living objects) in spring.

Comment: thanks for the help mark! but if i have dependency injection involved in object creation then also i should do new or alllow spring to create objects.

Comment: Yes, sure, this is exactly the third bullet from my answer... But I was under impression that the conversion like this doesn't impose any DI usage (Person class has no dependencies)...

Comment: no person class has address class in it.then i should go with prototype ?

Comment: address is also something that probably changes between different persons... Its rather a part of creation of the Person Object. So In this case I still don't think you should go with spring...

Comment: but prototype[person class] will take care of dependency injection so there should be no problem as if i make person prortotype address will also be prototype(means new address object is added to person class).just wanted to know why not spring

Comment: Yes, it will take care, but Address is also the object with data, so Spring can do new for you but which data will this new Address Object contain? It should be something like city, street, apt. etc... Spring doesn't manage the address data relevant for each possible person...

Comment: why spring will not manage.., when we create person object address object will be created and attached to that person class right?

Comment: Yes, spring will do new Address() and attach to person. But how it will populate the parameters? How spring will know that person Jack lives in NY, but person Nick lives in Chicago + other address data... Spring DI is about "behaviors" glue-ing, not about data manipulation

Comment: means lets say i intialise like this person1.name-: A  address1.ctry -:us,person2.name -: B address2.ctry-: uk.So if i do person1.address1.ctry it will not show US. and i am storing the data in db once it is created

Comment: I think you should try to implement with spring and see where it leads to complicated design. This data about A, US, etc. Can't be managed by spring as long as you don't have a very specific and static list of address.